# how to safely reallocate memory in C++ for char *array (it's for CustomString class)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I think my teacher was mostly telling us what are  the wrong ways to allocate memory ...

But I wasn't totally sure what is the correct way to safely reallocate more memory to a pointer. Purpose of reallocating memory to my mind is  because the old memory allocation is not large enough (e.g. when doing an prefix increment operator overload such as append character 'X', presumably you would need large enough new allocation to accomodate the endresult?)

QUESTIONS:

1. So I was left rather puzzled by what exactly is the correct way to reallocate memory to a char*c_string, because the old memoryallocation is not large enough anymore, and we need the larger memoryallocation instead (this happens with prefix increment operator overload)?
2. does my existing code have memoryleaks in the prefix increment operator overload?
3. how can I find memoryleaks when coding C++ in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows?

Basic information about my project:
The goal was to create your own CustomString class, and have char*pointer as a private instance variable of the CustomString class.

I have created my own CustomString class already, and I was supposed to make some operator overloads, such as addition operator, prefix increment operator.

The main purpose with addition operator is of course naturally string concatenation. And with the prefix increment operator, you just add a character 'X' at the end.

I can post here below my definitions for my already existing code.

CustomString.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class CustomString
{
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const CustomString &reference);//OUTPUT OPERATOR OVERLOADED as friend function

public:
    static const int MaxSize = 10;//classwide constant
    static int getNumberOfCustomStrings();

    CustomString(const char *namepointer="");// constructor
    //CustomString(char * pointer);//constructor w/parameters
    ~CustomString();//destructor
    CustomString(const CustomString &stringref);    //copy constructor w/dynamic datamember
    operator const char*() const; // IMPLICIT CONVERSION operator overloaded


     CustomString operator+( const CustomString &addedpart) const;  // PLUS OPERATOR OVERLOADED implemented as string concatenate
    const CustomString& operator=(const CustomString &ref); //ASSIGNMENT OPERATOR OVERLOADED works for dynamic strings as well
    const CustomString &operator++();//PREINCREMENT OPERATOR OVERLOADED
    CustomString operator++(int);//POSTINCREMENT OPERATOR OVERLOADEd
    char& operator[](int i) const;// INDEXING OPERATOR OVERLOADED

private:
    char * c_string;
    void list();
    static int numberOfCustomStrings;
};
```

From CustomString.cpp, here is the prefix increment piece of code

```
const CustomString & CustomString::operator++()// PREFIX INCREMENT OVERLOADED, adds an 'X' character into the dynamic instance variable(char*c_string)
{

    if (  strlen(c_string) == (MaxSize-1)   ) {
        cout << "error cannot increment any further" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    else {
        int oldlength = strlen(c_string) +1;
        char*newdata;
        newdata = new char[ oldlength+1  ]; //it has to be one char bigger allocation bevause one "X" soon will be added
        strcpy_s(newdata, oldlength+1, c_string);//put the old data into new allocation as the baseword
        newdata[oldlength-1] = 'X';
        newdata[oldlength] = '\0';
        delete c_string;//free the old memory
        c_string = newdata; //give  the new allocation to the dynamic instance variable
        return *this;

    }

}
```

I believe that I already did destructor, constructor and copy-constructor correctly, but I can also give their code

Constructor from CustomString.cpp

```
CustomString::CustomString(const char *pointer)// constructor
{
    if(   (strlen(pointer)+1) <=MaxSize   ){
    c_string = new char[strlen(pointer) + 1];
    strcpy_s(c_string, (strlen(pointer) + 1), pointer);
    numberOfCustomStrings++;
    }
    else {
        c_string = new char[MaxSize];
        //printf("char at last index was == %c \n", c_string[MaxSize-1]);
        int j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j <= (MaxSize-2); j++) {
            c_string[j] = pointer[j];
        }
        //printf("the last truechar was %c \n",pointer[MaxSize-2]);
        c_string[MaxSize - 1] = '\0';
        //printf("the last char was %c\n", pointer[MaxSize-1]);
        numberOfCustomStrings++;
    }

}
```

Here is copy-constructor from CustomString.cpp

```
CustomString::CustomString(const CustomString &ref)     //copy-constructor w/dynamic data member.
{
    c_string = new char[strlen(ref.c_string) + 1];  
    strcpy_s(c_string, strlen(ref.c_string) + 1, ref.c_string);
    numberOfCustomStrings++;
}
```

Here is destructor from CustomString.cpp

```
CustomString::~CustomString()   // destructor
{
    delete c_string;  
    cout << "destructor called!" << endl;
    numberOfCustomStrings--;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you are allocating memory as `char* newdata= new char[somesize];` and release it as `delete c_string`, It is a memory leak. Use `delete[] c_string` to release all the array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I asked about that same thing from my teacher, but he apparently gave me the wrong advice about delete operator with array.

Comment: `delete c_string` just free the memory of first element, `delete[] c_string` free the memory of the array. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

Comment: Did you find other faults than the lack of delete[] operator? I'm sorry, I'm really paranoid now about this whole thing.

Comment: As i see, just when you use `delete c_string`. Take care of where you reserving (`new`) and when to release (`delete`). Keep in mind this rule: Reserve, Use and Free.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
char *a = new char;
delete a;

char *array = new char[100];
delete [] array;
```

You can use visual leak detector to Locate a line